# Как из своего приложения нажать на кнопку в другом приложении? C++ WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi

В общем, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы нажималась кнопка в другом приложении.
Пытался ловить хендлер через FindWindow(); и делать SendMessage(); по этому хендлеру - не получилось.

```
switch (uMessage)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN) {
            hCalc = FindWindow(NULL, L"Window");
    HWND wnd;
            wnd = FindWindowEx(hCalc , 0, 0, L"Start");
        }
    SendMessage(wnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
        }
```

Comment: И в чем у вас проблема? Что вы не можете отследить нажатие кнопки "Start" в своем приложении?

Comment: нет,просто я запускаю своё приложение,после чего запускаю то,в котором хочу через своё нажать на кнопку,жмякаю Enter и 0 эмоций,не нажимается Start в том приложении

Comment: Нажатие кнопки мыши - ни разу не ее "отпускание", а целых два события. Вы шлете только одно

Comment: я и два события отправлял WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP.   Так же пробовал BM_CLICK И по отдельности пробовал,это просто фрагмент кода самой первой попытки)

Comment: Почему тогда вообще левый код в вопрос не пишете? Результат поиска окна проверяйте.

Comment: а как правильно проверять тот ли хендлер я получил? В Spy++ это Дескриптор?

Comment: Правильно - прочитать MSDN и найти там про успешность/неуспешность выполнения функции.

Comment: хендлер родительского окна у меня приходит верно,а правильно ли я ищу хендлер кнопки,быть может есть другой способ?

Comment: Правильно задать про это отдельный вопрос, а не комментарии засорять.